# Character Replacements

Tags: google-sheets

I have a UniCode string UniStr.

I also have a MAP of { UniCodeChar : otherMappedStrs }

I need the 'otherMappedStrs' version of UniStr.

Eg: UniStr = 'ABC', MAP = { 'A':'233','B':'#$','C':'9ij' }, Result = '233#$9ij'

I have come up with the formula below which works;

```
=ArrayFormula(JOIN("",VLOOKUP(REGEXEXTRACT(A1,REPT("(.)",LEN(A1))),MapRange,2,FALSE)))
```

The MAP being a whole character set (40 chars) is quite large.

1. I need to use this function in multiple spreadsheets. How can I subsume the MAP into the formula for portability ?
2. Is there a better way to *iterate* a string other than the REGEXEXTRACT method in formula ? This method has limitation for long strings.

I also tested the below formula. Problem here is it gives 2 results (or the size of the array within SUBSTITUTE replacement). If 3 substitutions made, then it gives three results. Can this be resolved ?

```
=ArrayFormula(SUBSTITUTE(A1,{"s","i"},{"@","#"}))
```

EDIT;

@Tom 's first solution appears best for my case (1) REGEX has an upper limit on search criteria which does not hinder in your solution (2) Feels fast (did not do empirical testing) (3) This is a better way to iterate string characters, I believe (you answered my Q2 - thanks)

I digress here. I wish google would introduce Named-Formulas or Formula-Aliases. In this case, hypothetically below. I have sent feed back along those lines many times. Nothing :(

```
 MyFormula($str) == ArrayFormula(join(,vlookup(mid($str,row(indirect("1:"&len($str))),1), { "A","233";"B","#$";"C","9ij" },2,false)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have several different Qs, but considering only portability, perhaps something like the following would help:

```
=join(,switch(arrayformula(regexextract(A1&"",rept("(.)",len(A1)))),"A",233,"B","#$","C","9ij"))
```

extended with 37 more pairs.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how long you want your strings to be, but the more traditional

```
=ArrayFormula(join(,vlookup(mid(A1,row(indirect("1:"&len(A1))),1), { "A","233";"B","#$";"C","9ij" },2,false)))
```

seems a bit more robust for long strings.

For a more radical idea, supposing the maximum length of your otherMappedStrings is 3 characters, then you could try:

```
=ArrayFormula(join(,trim(mid("233 #$9ij",find(mid(A1,row(indirect("1:"&len(A1))),1), "ABC")*3-2,3))))
```

where I have put a space in before #$ to pad it out to 3 characters.

Incidentally the original VLOOKUP is not case sensitive. If you want this behaviour, use SEARCH instead of FIND.